# Django Haystack: Narrowing by facet with a space in it does not narrow

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I am having issues `narrowing` my `SearchQuerySet` by facets that have a space in them.

I am using django-haystack with ElasticSearch

I have the following Index:

```
class ProductIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):

    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title') 

    category = indexes.MultiValueField(faceted=True) # m2m field
    weight = indexes.MultiValueField(faceted=True, null=True) 
    title_auto = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='title') # for autocomplete

def get_model(self):
    return Product

def prepare_category(self, obj):
    return [(cat.title) for cat in obj.categories.all()]

def prepare_weight(self, obj):
    return [(meta.value) for meta in obj.productmeta_set.filter(label="weight")]
```

But I'm getting some very odd results when trying to query it:

The total facet counts:

```
>>> sqs = SearchQuerySet().all().facet("category")
>>> sqs.facet_counts()
{'fields': {'category': [(u'Wall Tiles', 1028), (u'Floor Tiles', 440), (u'Baths', 49), (u'Basins', 25), (u'Toilets', 19)]}, 'dates': {}, 'queries': {}}
```

I have managed to get the correct value for Wall Tiles like so:

```
>>> sqs.narrow("category:%s" % sqs.query.clean("Wall Tiles") ).count()
1028 # correct value
```

(This is using the method used in [FacetedSearchForm](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/blob/master/haystack/forms.py))

But strangely enough if I use the same approach for floor tiles I still get all the tiles:

```
>>> sqs.narrow("category:%s" % sqs.query.clean("Floor Tiles") ).count()
1468 # incorrect (count of floor tiles + wall tiles)
```

Even more perculiar is that if I change the above Wall Tiles query to use `_exact`, it returns the count of both!

```
>>> sqs.narrow("category_exact:%s" % sqs.query.clean("Wall Tiles") ).count()
1468
```

It works fine for categories that do not have a space in them.

I'm sure I'm missing something basic here .. but I can't for the life of me see why I'm getting such odd results!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely need to set up custom Elasticsearch analyzers for your `category` field. The default analyzer tokenizes words.  See http://www.wellfireinteractive.com/blog/custom-haystack-elasticsearch-backend/ for some info on customizing things with Haystack+Elasticsearch.

Your results may vary, but things like this are the reasons I've started to move away from Haystack and use the specific search engine directly - you can get a lot more flexibility and power out of the direct, non-abstracted solution.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer, even though I ended up taking a different approach. This is a more _correct_ way to do it. 

What I did was to `slugify` my faceted fields in the `_prepare()` method. I then added a `deslugify` templatetag to handle the display of the facets in the frontend.